# What grows/flowers like trumpet vine, but isn't?

Tags: identification, vines

Found a 40 ft plus heavy thick vine growing in mid-California that climbs like a trumpet vine,  has 4 inch flowers shaped almost the same as trumpet vine flowers, with the outer inch reddish pink but with a 3 inch yellow neck inside and out, and with glossy opposing single leaves instead of 3-4 ft compound leaves.
What is it?

I first thought it might be a Mandevilla, then maybe a  Crossvine, but the flowers of both aren't right.  The flowers of this vine are too long, 4 inches, to be a Mandevilla or Crossvine, it has no seedpod, and the 5 petal tips aren't pointed but are rounded, with a v in the middle of each petal tip, like the top of a drawn heart. See photo.

[image: Unknown vine]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I'm confused - I'm pretty sure the photo now present isn't the one I saw yesterday, and because of this photo, it's now obvious it's one of the Bignonias, B. buccinatoria, commonly known as Mexican Blood vine; this variety is called B. 'Cherere' or simply Bignonia buccinatoria, although there are other varieties too. Note that Bignonia is now reclassified and named Distictis buccinatoria, which comes in various colours. Link to pic below

http://www.tecnowoodgarden.it/27-bignonia-cherere.html

Some interesting background information in the link below, plus cultural information re this plant

http://www.hgtv.com/design/outdoor-design/landscaping-and-hardscaping/twin-trumpets-not-identical-after-all

Comment: Asker updated the photo with a better one, according to the comment on the other answer.